# How to include different groups related tests work in testng and maven project

Tags: testng

When the maven project is tested by `Run As > Maven test`

There are 477 testing tests shown as success, all of these belong to `@Test(groups=unit)...`

What if we need to include other groups `@Test(groups=unit)` also to the testing configuration??

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many groups as you want. :

```
package com.stack.JarCreation;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeGroups;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNgGroups {

    @BeforeGroups({"gp","group"})
    public void beforeGroup(){
        System.out.println("Before Group");
    }

    @Test(priority=1,groups="gp")
    public void first(){
        System.out.println("first");
    }

    @Test(priority=2,groups="gp")
    public void second(){
        System.out.println("second");
    }

    @Test(priority=3)
    public void third(){
        System.out.println("third");
    }
    @Test(priority=4,dependsOnGroups="gp")
    public void four(){
        System.out.println("four");
    }
    @Test(priority=5)
    public void five(){
        System.out.println("five");
    }
    @Test(priority=6,groups="group")
    public void Six(){
        System.out.println("Six");
    }

}
```

Output when you run it as a suite :

```
Before Group
first
second
third
four
five
Before Group
Six
```

Output when you run only test case **four** :

```
Before Group
first
second
four
```

Explanation : First it will run dependent test cases then it will run this test case at last. if any of the test case fails then this test case will be skipped.

Hope this will help.